# Rendering in django template paragraph behaves weird

Tags: django, templates, django-forms, django-templates, rendering

I have the following code in my template:

```
<p>{{ form.end_at }}</p>
<p>{{ form.weekdays }}</p>
```

It renders as follows:

```
<p><input type="text" name="end_at"></p>
<p></p>
<ul>
    <li>..</li>
    ..
</ul>
<p></p>
```

So why does the first call places the **input** in the **p** and the second creates two **p** tags instead of placing the **ul** in the **p** as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Django doing this, its the browser "normalizing" what it sees as invalid markup. According to [HTML spec](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), `<p>` tags can't contain `<ul>` tags:

> List elements (in particular, ol and ul elements) cannot be children
>   of p elements.

The spec recommends either closing the paragraph before staring the list: `<p>...</p><ul>...</ul><p>...</p>` (which is exactly what the browser did) or to use `<div>` instead of `<p>`.

To test, try downloading the page using `wget` and opening in a text editor - you'll see that the generated markup is what you told Django to render, no extra tags added.